# Regular expression for handling btn class changes while upgrading to bootstrap 3

Tags: regex, twitter-bootstrap-3, notepad++, regex-lookarounds

I am migrating large application from bootstrap v2 to bootstrap 3.I am using Notepad++ to search using regular expression for searching for the old class names to replace. In bootstrap 3, btn class usage without any other in-built btn styles i.e btn-pimary,btn-success,btn-info,btn-warning,btn-danger,btn-link should be changed to btn btn-default.

So I need a regex pattern which finds btn occurrences in these lines

```
 <button class="btn btn-mini" />
 <button class="btn btn-small" />
 <button class="btn btn-large"/>
 <button class="btn"/>
 <button class="btn "/>
 <button class=" btn"/>
```

but does not find btn occurrences in

```
<button class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" />
<button class="btn btn-small btn-success" />
<button class="btn btn-large btn-info"/>
<button class="btn btn-error"/>
```

I have (?<=["'\s])btn(?=["'\s]) this regex but it searches for all btns including the btn-primary, btn-success etc. How to modify it so that it just matches the btn when it is used without the btn-primary, btn-success etc.

Comment: could you please be more specific about what exactly should be matched from the texts you proviuded? Only `btn` where it is not followed by any of the "btn-" classes?

Comment: I need to search only "btn" where it is not followed by any of the following class btn-pimary,btn-success,btn-info,btn-warning,btn-danger,btn-link

If there is btn followed by btn-mini and btn-primary dont match.
If there is btn followed by btn-mini|btn-small|btn-large without any of above classes match only btn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?<=class=")\s?btn\s?(btn-)?(mini|small|large)?\s?(?=")
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/VhwAym/2

Capturing only btn:

```
(?<=class=")\s?btn(?=\s?(?:btn-)?(?:mini|small|large)?\s?")
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/VhwAym/3

Comment: thanks for the script.It correct matches the where btn is followed by btn-mini pr btn-small or btn-large but matches whole btn btn-small. I need to match only btn

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need lookarounds for this one - just some simple alternations will suffice, using the pattern

```
"\s*btn\s*(?:btn-(?:mini|small|large))?\s*"
```

[Demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FVZgzK/2)